# sbt always doing a full rebuild on spurious source changes

Tags: scala, sbt

My only guess is that there is something wrong with my build configuration, but every time I compile it is recompiling everything.  Digging deeper "last compile" always tells me

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 28 Scala sources and 78 Java sources to /home/me/foo/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[success] Total time: 34 s, completed Nov 8, 2013 12:35:18 PM
> last compile
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set(/home/me/foo/scala/Bar.scala, ...)
[debug]     added: Set(scala/Bar.scala, ...)
[debug]     modified: Set()
...
[debug] Recompiling all 106 sources: invalidated sources (56) exceeded 50.0% of all sources
...
```

where for each of my Scala source files, they are in the remove set contains with their fully qualified path, and in the added set they have their relative path I use in my configuration.  I have a mixed Scala and Java project, so could that be an issue?  Though "last compile" never mentions the Java files.

My configuration looks like:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
  )
  val jettyVersion = "7.6.7.v20120910"

  val webHome = System.getenv("WEB_HOME")

  val webJars = 
  Seq("servlet-api-2.5.jar", 
      "annotations.jar",
      "jetty-server-" + jettyVersion + ".jar",
      "jetty-client-" + jettyVersion + ".jar",
      "jetty-http-" + jettyVersion + ".jar",
      "jetty-http-" + jettyVersion + ".jar")
    .map(webHome + "/lib/java/" + _)
  val classes = Seq("build/jars/Foo.classes")

  val jarPath = (webJars ++ classes).map(file).classpath

  val sourcePaths = 
    inConfig(Compile)(Defaults.configSettings) ++
    Seq(
      unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("scala"),
      unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("build/java"),
      unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("java"),
      unmanagedJars in Compile ++= jarPath)

  val root = Project("root", file("."), settings = (buildSettings ++ sourcePaths))
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm screwing up here?

Comment: So I was able to resolve the problem by using the absolute path in the unmanagedSources.  Doing that isn't too much of a burden but it isn't obvious why that is necessary.

Comment: See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/923.

Answer (score 0):

I put th following line at the end of my build.sbt:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

solved my problem, since due to IDE compatibility my sources are directly under `src` with no `main` nor `scala` folders.